# How to setup a grammar that can handle ambiguity

Tags: python, grammar, lark-parser

I'm trying to create a grammar to parse some Excel-like formulas I have devised, where a special character in the beginning of a string signifies a different source. For example, `$` can signify a string, so "`$This is text`" would be treated as a string input in the program and `&` can signify a function, so `&foo()` can be treated as a call to the internal function `foo`.

The problem I'm facing is how to construct the grammar properly. For example, This is a simplified version as a MWE:

```py
grammar = r'''start: instruction

?instruction: simple
            | func

STARTSYMBOL: "!"|"#"|"$"|"&"|"~"
SINGLESTR: (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" ")*
simple: STARTSYMBOL [SINGLESTR] (WORDSEP SINGLESTR)*
ARGSEP: ",," // argument separator
WORDSEP: "," // word separator
CONDSEP: ";;" // condition separator
STAR: "*"
func: STARTSYMBOL SINGLESTR "(" [simple|func] (ARGSEP simple|func)* ")"

%import common.LETTER
%import common.WORD
%import common.DIGIT
%ignore ARGSEP
%ignore WORDSEP
'''
parser = lark.Lark(grammar, parser='earley')
```

So, with this grammar, things like: `$This is a string`, `&foo()`, `&foo(#arg1)`, `&foo($arg1,,#arg2)` and `&foo(!w1,w2,w3,,!w4,w5,w6)` are all parsed as expected. But if I'd like to add more flexibility to my `simple` terminal, then I need to start fiddling around with the `SINGLESTR` token definition which is not convenient.

### What have I tried

The part that I cannot get past is that if I want to have a string including parentheses (which are literals of `func`), then I cannot handle them in my current situation.

- If I add the parentheses in `SINGLESTR`, then I get `Expected STARTSYMBOL`, because it's getting mixed up with the `func` definition and it thinks that a function argument should be passed, which makes sense.
- If I redefine the grammar to reserve the ampersand symbol for functions only and add the parentheses in `SINGLESTR`, then I can parse a string with parentheses, but every function I'm trying to parse gives `Expected LPAR`.

My intent is that anything starting with a `$` would be parsed as a `SINGLESTR` token and then I could parse things like `&foo($first arg (has) parentheses,,$second arg)`.

My solution, for now, is that I'm using 'escape' words like LEFTPAR and RIGHTPAR in my strings and I've written helper functions to change those into parentheses when I process the tree. So, `$This is a LEFTPARtestRIGHTPAR` produces the correct tree and when I process it, then this gets translated to `This is a (test)`.

To formulate a general question: Can I define my grammar in such a way that some characters that are special to the grammar are treated as normal characters in some situations and as special in any other case?

---

### EDIT 1

Based on a comment from `jbndlr` I revised my grammar to create individual modes based on the start symbol:

```py
grammar = r'''start: instruction

?instruction: simple
            | func

SINGLESTR: (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" ") (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" "|"("|")")*
FUNCNAME: (LETTER+) (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_")* // no parentheses allowed in the func name
DB: "!" SINGLESTR (WORDSEP SINGLESTR)*
TEXT: "$" SINGLESTR
MD: "#" SINGLESTR
simple: TEXT|DB|MD
ARGSEP: ",," // argument separator
WORDSEP: "," // word separator
CONDSEP: ";;" // condition separator
STAR: "*"
func: "&" FUNCNAME "(" [simple|func] (ARGSEP simple|func)* ")"

%import common.LETTER
%import common.WORD
%import common.DIGIT
%ignore ARGSEP
%ignore WORDSEP
'''
```

This falls (somewhat) under my second test case. I can parse all the `simple` types of strings (TEXT, MD or DB tokens that can contain parentheses) and functions that are empty; for example, `&foo()` or `&foo(&bar())` parse correctly. The moment I put an argument within a function (no matter which type), I get an `UnexpectedEOF Error: Expected ampersand, RPAR or ARGSEP`. As a proof of concept, if I remove the parentheses from the definition of SINGLESTR in the new grammar above, then everything works as it should, but I'm back to square one.

Comment: You do have characters that identify what's coming after them (your `STARTSYMBOL`) and you add separators and parentheses where required to be clear; I don't see any ambiguity here. You'd still have to split your `STARTSYMBOL` list into individual items to be distinguishable.

Comment: I'm gonna post an answer real soon, have been working on it for several days now.

Comment: I supplied an answer. Although it's only 2 hours until the bounty expires, you can still manually award the bounty in the following grace period of 24 hours. If my answer isn't good please tell me soon and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import lark
grammar = r'''start: instruction

?instruction: simple
            | func

MIDTEXTRPAR: /\)+(?!(\)|,,|$))/
SINGLESTR: (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" ") (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" "|"("|MIDTEXTRPAR)*
FUNCNAME: (LETTER+) (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_")* // no parentheses allowed in the func name
DB: "!" SINGLESTR (WORDSEP SINGLESTR)*
TEXT: "$" SINGLESTR
MD: "#" SINGLESTR
simple: TEXT|DB|MD
ARGSEP: ",," // argument separator
WORDSEP: "," // word separator
CONDSEP: ";;" // condition separator
STAR: "*"
func: "&" FUNCNAME "(" [simple|func] (ARGSEP simple|func)* ")"

%import common.LETTER
%import common.WORD
%import common.DIGIT
%ignore ARGSEP
%ignore WORDSEP
'''

parser = lark.Lark(grammar, parser='earley')
parser.parse("&foo($first arg (has) parentheses,,$second arg)")
```

Output:

```
Tree(start, [Tree(func, [Token(FUNCNAME, 'foo'), Tree(simple, [Token(TEXT, '$first arg (has) parentheses')]), Token(ARGSEP, ',,'), Tree(simple, [Token(TEXT, '$second arg')])])])
```

I hope it's what you were looking for.

Those have been crazy few days. I tried lark and failed. I also tried `persimonious` and `pyparsing`. All of these different parsers all had the same problem with the 'argument' token consuming the right parenthesis that was part of the function, eventually failing because the function's parentheses weren't closed.

The trick was to figure out how do you define a right parenthesis that's "not special". See the regular expression for `MIDTEXTRPAR` in the code above. I defined it as a right parenthesis that is not followed by argument separation or by end of string. I did that by using the regular expression extension `(?!...)` which matches only if it's not followed by `...` but doesn't consume characters. Luckily it even allows matching end of string inside this special regular expression extension.

EDIT:

The above mentioned method only works if you don't have an argument ending with a ), because then the MIDTEXTRPAR regular expression won't catch that ) and will think that's the end of the function even though there are more arguments to process. Also, there may be ambiguities such as ...asdf),,..., it may be an end of a function declaration inside an argument, or a 'text-like' ) inside an argument and the function declaration goes on.

This problem is related to the fact that what you describe in your question is not a context-free grammar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) for which parsers such as lark exist. Instead it is a context-sensitive grammar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar).

The reason for it being a context sensitive grammar is because you need the parser to 'remember' that it is nested inside a function, and how many levels of nesting there are, and have this memory available inside the grammar's syntax in some way.

EDIT2:

Also take a look at the following parser that is context-sensitive, and seems to solve the problem, but has an exponential time complexity in the number of nested functions, as it tries to parse all possible function barriers until it finds one that works. I believe it has to have an exponential complexity has since it's not context-free.

```
_funcPrefix = '&'
_debug = False

class ParseException(Exception):
    pass

def GetRecursive(c):
    if isinstance(c,ParserBase):
        return c.GetRecursive()
    else:
        return c

class ParserBase:
    def __str__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + ": [" + ','.join(str(x) for x in self.contents) +"]"
    def GetRecursive(self):
        return (type(self).__name__,[GetRecursive(c) for c in self.contents])

class Simple(ParserBase):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.contents = [s]

class MD(Simple):
    pass

class DB(ParserBase):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.contents = s.split(',')

class Func(ParserBase):
    def __init__(self,s):
        if s[-1] != ')':
            raise ParseException("Can't find right parenthesis: '%s'" % s)
        lparInd = s.find('(')
        if lparInd < 0:
            raise ParseException("Can't find left parenthesis: '%s'" % s)
        self.contents = [s[:lparInd]]
        argsStr = s[(lparInd+1):-1]
        args = list(argsStr.split(',,'))
        i = 0
        while i<len(args):
            a = args[i]
            if a[0] != _funcPrefix:
                self.contents.append(Parse(a))
                i += 1
            else:
                j = i+1
                while j<=len(args):
                    nestedFunc = ',,'.join(args[i:j])
                    if _debug:
                        print(nestedFunc)
                    try:
                        self.contents.append(Parse(nestedFunc))
                        break
                    except ParseException as PE:
                        if _debug:
                            print(PE)
                        j += 1
                if j>len(args):
                    raise ParseException("Can't parse nested function: '%s'" % (',,'.join(args[i:])))
                i = j

def Parse(arg):
    if arg[0] not in _starterSymbols:
        raise ParseException("Bad prefix: " + arg[0])
    return _starterSymbols[arg[0]](arg[1:])

_starterSymbols = {_funcPrefix:Func,'$':Simple,'!':DB,'#':MD}

P = Parse("&foo($first arg (has)) parentheses,,&f($asdf,,&nested2($23423))),,&second(!arg,wer))")
print(P)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(P.GetRecursive())
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as intended! Awarded the bounty as you don't need to escape the parentheses in any way. You went the extra mile and it shows! There is still the edge case of a 'text' argument ending with a parenthesis, but I'll just have to live with that one. You also explained the ambiguities in a clear way and I'll just need to test that a bit more, but I think for my purposes this will work very well. Thanks for also providing more info on the context-sensitive grammar. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Dima1982 Take a look at the edit, I made a parser that can perhaps solve your problem at the cost of an exponential time complexity.
Also, I thought about it and if your problem is of a practical value, escaping the parentheses might be the simplest solution. Or Making the function parenthesis something else, like delimiting the end of a functions argument list with `&` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is arguments of function are enclosed in parenthesis where one of the arguments may contain parenthesis.
One of the possible solution is use backspace \ before ( or ) when it is a part of String

```
  SINGLESTR: (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" ") (LETTER+|DIGIT+|"_"|" "|"\("|"\)")*
```

Similar solution used by C, to include double quotes(") as a part of string constant where string constant is enclosed in double quotes.

```
  example_string1='&f(!g\()'
  example_string2='&f(#g)'
  print(parser.parse(example_string1).pretty())
  print(parser.parse(example_string2).pretty())
```

Output is

```
   start
     func
       f
       simple   !g\(

   start
     func
      f
      simple    #g
```

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same as OP's own solution of replacing "(" and ")" with LEFTPAR and RIGHTPAR.